# "Some requested scopes cannot be shown" error when performing OAuth2 flow for Datastudio API

Tags: google-oauth, looker-studio

I'm trying to use the [Datastudio API](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/api) to create a small script that I plan to use at a later point to manipulate asset permissions as [it won't be possible to do so via the Google Drive API in the future](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9460734).

When I perform an OAuth2 flow trying to authorize the indicated scopes

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastudio
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
openid
```

I get the following error:

[image: Screenshot of "Some requested scopes cannot be shown" error]

When I remove the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastudio`, the flow works just fine.

The Datastudio API has been enabled in the Google Cloud console for the specific project. Also, the account that I am trying to authorize against belongs to a G Suite Enterprise domain.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Data Studio API only supports OAuth2 clients of type "Web Application", not "Installed Application".

Comment: I'd like to use the API for my customers, who can't be expected to configure domain wide delegation. At the end of the guidance:
https://developers.google.com/datastudio/api
...it states " Programmatically getting an OAuth token is out of scope for this doc, but Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs should get you started.", which is what I'm working on (and have connected to countless other Google APIs in the past)
I keep ending up with the same 400, even if I try using the OAuth 2.0 Playground
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
Any ideas anyone please?

Comment: The way I read the documentation, it's currently not possible to use the Data Studio API without a Google Workspace / Cloud Identity domain for which domain-wide delegation is enabled.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this problem?